# Solution of Diffusion equation with exponential integrator

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-exponential, numerical-calculus

It is well known that stiff differential equations can be well tackled with the exponential integrator. I was trying to solve a diffusion equation with an exponential integrator and got stuck at matrix exponentiation.

The equation that I am trying to solve is the following,
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(D(x)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)-\frac{f}{E(x)}$$.
Using central differencing I got,

$$\frac{dF}{dt}=\mathcal{A}F$$
where $F$ is a vector $(f_{0},f_{1},...,f_{n})$ consisting the value of $f$ at $n+1$ discrete points. $\mathcal{A}$ is an usual tridagnal matrix arising from central differencing of the diffusion term.
With exponential integrator, the evolution of $F$ is given by,
$$F^{n+1}=e^{\mathcal{A}dt}F^{n}$$
where $dt$ is the timestepping.

I am stuck while exponentiation the tridiagonal matrix $\mathcal{A}$. How to exponentiate the matrix in C ? Is there any algorithm which can do it or do I need to approximate the exponential in the following way,
$$e^{\mathcal{A}dt}\approx\sum_{i=0}^{k}\frac{(\mathcal{A}dt)^{i}}{i!}$$
approximating up to $k$.

Comment: can you diagonalize $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options:

1. Find a Similarity transform $S$ that diagonalizes $A$, and then $e^{A dt}=S^{-1} e^{Ddt}S$ with $D$ diagonal.
2. Realize that in any case you are dealing with an discrete time approximation ($A$ changes with time) and you can use a rational (Cayley transform) approximation $e^{dtA}\sim {(I+dt A)\over (I-dt A)}$ which is higher order, and implicitly solvable.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I have a doubt regarding the second option that you have mentioned. How to compute $\frac{I+dtA}{I-dtA}$ ? It seems division of two matrices.

Comment: $F^{n+1}={(I+dt A)\over (I-dt A)}F^{n} \rightarrow (I-dt A)F^{n+1}=(I+dt A)F^{n} $, which can be solved for $F^{n+1}$ without direct inversion.